# dialogflow ES Avtar update is not showing?

Tags: dialogflow-es

hi I am try to update the avatar pic. however I can't see the update avatar button ,
when you go to setting and try to update the avatar !,
I search all the knowledge in the dialog flow es is not showing these topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can now change the avatar by defining the agent avatar URI in the console (I used link of an image on my replication):
[image]

Sample JSON representation:

```
{
  "parent": string,
  "displayName": string,
  "defaultLanguageCode": string,
  "supportedLanguageCodes": [
    string
  ],
  "timeZone": string,
  "description": string,
  "avatarUri": string, #Enter uri string here for the avatar
  "enableLogging": boolean,
  "matchMode": enum (MatchMode),
  "classificationThreshold": number,
  "apiVersion": enum (ApiVersion),
  "tier": enum (Tier)
}
```

As documented here in this article:
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/Agent